# camera rotates pointerlockcontrols

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I have used mrdoob's PointerLockControls.js example for this project. Everything works fine until I change the

```
    camera.position.set(2, 2, 3 );
```

to this

```
    camera.position.set(1100, 150, -50 );
```

It seems to 'rotate' along the z axis instead of just looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
controls.getObject().position.set( 1100, 150, -50 );
```

This is because of the clever way `PointerLockControls` handles camera movement.