# The camera rotates in a wrong way when its position is not (0,0,0) with PointerLockControls

Tags: three.js, pointerlock

**three.js r91**

I changed [the PointerLockControls example](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html) a little on [line 173](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/28894ccbc0787257074dd21cfedacb844bfcca88/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html#L173):

```js
camera.position.set(100, 0, 0);
controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls( camera );
controls.getObject().position.set(100, 0, 0);
scene.add( controls.getObject() );
```

When I move the mouse to look around, you can see the rotation of the camera is incorrect-it is not rotating around itself but somewhere else.

You can see I have added `controls.getObject().position.set(100, 0, 0);`, attempting to solve the problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15192754/3427520) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36191229/3427520). But it doesn't work.

See [this codepen post](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmwNWx) for a complete example.

What should I do to make the camera rotate around itself normally when moving the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

```
camera.position.set(100, 0, 0);
var cameraPos = camera.position.clone();//save original position
camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);//reset to zero
controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls( camera );
controls.getObject().position.copy(cameraPos);//set original position to the control object
scene.add( controls.getObject() );
```

In this way, `camera.position`(the local position of the camera) will always be `(0,0,0)` but the world position of the camera is correct.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove *camera.position.set(100, 0, 0);* line and keep others

Comment: No. I just WANT to add `camera.position.set(100, 0, 0);`.